# Losing queued tasks in Python apply_async

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing, executable

I am attempting to write a wrapper that iterates through running another program with different input files. The program (over which I have no control, but need to use) needs to be run out of the same directory as the input file(s). So far my method is to use OS-module to change/create directory structure, use apply-async to run the program given a sub-directory, and each child in apply-async changes directory, creates the file, and the first 8 processes run successfully (i have 8 virtual cores)

However, I am queueing up to 100 of these processes (they run a simulation which takes a few minutes, I'm looking to optimize).  I use "call" on the outside executable I am running. I thought everything was going great, but then after the 8th simulation runs, everything stops, I check 0 processes are running. It is as if the queue forgot about the other processes.

What can I do to fix this? I know my RAM only goes up about 300 MB out of 8GB.

Do I need to look into implementing some sort of queue myself that waits for the exit code of the simulation executable?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I doubt anyone can help unless you show minimal code reproducing the problem.  Details matter *a lot* when using `multiprocessing`, and we have none here.  For example, are you using a callback?  Are you using the `.get()` method to eventually retrieve the result?  Add a million others ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe better than nothing.  This shows a correct way to use `apply_async()`, and demonstrates that - yup - there's no problem creating many more tasks than processes.  I'd tell you how this differs from what you're doing, but I have no idea what you're doing ;-)

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def work(i):
    from time import sleep
    sleep(2.0 if i & 1 else 1.0)
    return i*i

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = mp.Pool(4)
    results = [pool.apply_async(work, (i,)) for i in range(100)]
    results = [r.get() for r in results]
    print len(results), results
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Comment: I realize you answered this forever ago, I was doing essentially the same thing you are, with one exception, thats that I'm using the subprocess.call() function to start an executable. Are you aware of any issues with that? Thanks

Comment: @MatthewMozdzen, I have no way to guess what you're doing.  Offhand, a `Pool(4)` ensures that no more than 4 child processes are created.  Depending on the (unknown to me) *details* of what you're doing, `subprocess.call()` in a loop may create an unbounded number of child processes simultaneously active.